# 2 Pandas Compare and determine threshold value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I compare 2 different pandas csv file(csv to pandas) and due to threshold value return True or False.

For example
A=[101 202 405] and B=[103 201 409] , Threshold value =+-5
B-A=[2 -1 4] so it will return True

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot.

My program like ; 
a=pd.read_csv(str(myvariable)+'/'+str(myvariable)+'.csv')
b=pd.read_csv(str(counter)+'/'+str(counter)+'.csv')
c=((b-a).abs().le(3)) and I can see ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). what is solutiion for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After difference get absolute value by [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html), compare by [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) (`<=`) or [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) (`<`) and check if all values are `True`s by [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
A = pd.Series([101, 202, 405])
B = pd.Series([103, 201, 409]) 

#less or equal   
C = (B - A).abs().le(5).all()
#less
#C = (B - A).abs().lt(5).all()
print (C)
True
```

**Details**:

```
print ((B - A).abs())
0    2
1    1
2    4
dtype: int64

print ((B - A).abs().le(5))
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```

EDIT:

For read DataFrames need pure python, because unstandard format (pandas best suport read scalars by `read_csv`):

```
with open('1.csv') as f:
    data1 = f.readlines()

data1 = [[float(y) for y in x.strip().strip('[').strip(']').split()] for x in data1] 
A = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print (A)
       0      1      2
0  166.0  156.0  153.0
1  166.0  156.0  153.0
2  168.0  158.0  154.0

with open('2.csv') as f:
    data2 = f.readlines()

data2 = [[float(y) for y in x.strip().strip('[').strip(']').split()] for x in data2] 
B = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print (B)
       0      1      2
0  142.0  130.0  127.0
1  142.0  130.0  127.0
2  142.0  130.0  126.0
```

For compare DataFrames use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
#python 0.24+ solution
C = (B - A).abs().le(5).all(axis=None)
#alternative for python bellow
#C = (B - A).abs().le(5).values.all(axis=None)
print (C)
False
```

Comment: a=pd.read_csv(str(myvariable)+'.csv')
b=pd.read_csv(str(counter)+'.csv')
c=((b.all()-a.all()).abs().le(3)) when I do like that I can see ; ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). what is solutiion for it?

Comment: What is print (a) ?

Comment: I just fix it can you check and tell me what is the problem?

Comment: @Emre - What is `print (a.head())` ? Can you edit question?

Comment: @jazrael As you know I convert csv file to pandas with  pd_read_csv maybe that is why I can see error like ; TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @Emre - What is `print (A.info())` ? And what is `print (B.info())` ?

Comment: @jazrael <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
[166. 156. 153.]    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
[142. 130. 127.]    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
None

Comment: @Emre - You need convert colunmns to numeric, so need `C = (B.astype(float) - A.astype(float) ).abs().le(5).all(axis=None)`. But it depends of data, need working only with numeric columns, string columns have to be reoved

Comment: @jazrael ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[142. 130. 127.]' shit :D

Comment: @Emre - are data confidental?

Comment: no its not . I just check each video first 3 frames and compare with other videos

Comment: @Emre - Is possible share your csv file (gdocs, dropbox, similar)? Or send it to my email from my profile?

Comment: what about if I add extra column for another value? Its last question :) @jezrael